# Wordpress Question - Custom Post Types

Tags: wordpress, themes, custom-post-type

I have got a custom theme with a functions.php, Now I am trying to create an easy to update portfolio section

Admin section includes

upload multiple images for a slider
display a list of skills used in project
Button to visit the project website
Brief text
Solution Text.

So far added the following to my functions php:

```
<?php
$themename = "AWDTheme";
$shortname = "ts";

add_filter('the_content_more_link', 'remove_more_jump_link');

    add_action('init', 'create_portfolio');
    function create_portfolio() {
        $portfolio_args = array(
            'label' => __('Portfolio'),
            'singular_label' => __('Portfolio'),
            'public' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'rewrite' => true,
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail')
        );
        register_post_type('portfolio',$portfolio_args);
    }

    add_action("admin_init", "add_portfolio");
    add_action('save_post', 'update_website_url');
    function add_portfolio(){
        add_meta_box("portfolio_details", "Portfolio Options", "portfolio_options", "portfolio", "normal", "low");
    }
    function portfolio_options(){
        global $post;
        $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
        $website_url = $custom["website_url"][0];
?>
    <div id="portfolio-options">
        <label>Website URL:</label><input name="website_url" value="<?php echo $website_url; ?>" />     
    </div><!--end portfolio-options-->   
<?php
    }
    function update_website_url(){
        global $post;
        update_post_meta($post->ID, "website_url", $_POST["website_url"]);
    }
    add_filter("manage_edit-portfolio_columns", "portfolio_edit_columns");
add_action("manage_posts_custom_column",  "portfolio_columns_display");

function portfolio_edit_columns($portfolio_columns){
    $portfolio_columns = array(
        "cb" => "<input type=\"checkbox\" />",
        "title" => "Client Name",
        "description" => "Description",
    );
    return $portfolio_columns;
}

function portfolio_columns_display($portfolio_columns){
    switch ($portfolio_columns)
    {
        case "description":
            the_excerpt();
            break;              
    }
}
?>
```

which generates the custom post type portfolio, and gives an input box to add the url of the project.

What I am stuck with is the way to upload the multiple images for the slider if its just to use the editor and don-t try and code wordpress then i can do it, but want to make it easier to updat and add new posts in this category so uploading 3 images and that was the slider sorted would be a great help.

Now the list of skills is another thing im not sure about how to implement i want the ouput to be:

- Skill 1
- Skill 2
- Skill 3

so like a field where you type the skill in and click add to list then it goes blank to add another, hope that makes sense.

If someone can lend a hand i would much appreciate it, all help appreciated.

Thanks
Joe

Comment: Dude, don't completely change your question after you post it. I answered your first question -- you need to create new questions, not write a new question in the same post once your first is answered.

Comment: The harm is that you have answers like mine that don't relate to the question anymore. Editing a question is for *clarifying*, not changing the entire question. Good luck with finding your new question's answer, although you'll need to unaccept mine before I can delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would familiarize myself with pods and go that route: http://podscms.org/

Otherwise, you'll need to make a special query outside of the post loop inside your slideshow mark-up that draws upon your custom post type and either loops through all its image attachments, or looks to a custom field that has all their paths.

As for the skills functionality, I would recommend [WPAlchemy_MetaBox](http://www.farinspace.com/wpalchemy-metabox/). Its a PHP class can be used to create WordPress meta boxes quickly. In your instance, you'll need to use the `have_fields_and_multi($name)` function: http://www.farinspace.com/wpalchemy-metabox/#have_fields_and_multi